# Limit search form to 4 custom post types only

Tags: custom-post-types, search

I'm able to limit the search to one post type which works like a charm.

This code works:  `<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="videos"/>`

However, how do I limit the search to be performed in 4 custom post types instead of just one.

The post types are "videos, e-courses, e-books and white-papers".

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the input with 4 inputs like this :

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="videos" />
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="e-courses" />
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="e-books" />
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="white-papers" />
```

You may get more detail about a complete code in [this article](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-advanced-search-form-in-wordpress-for-custom-post-types/)

Comment: Curious use of form inputs to set an array of options...