# How to search for many post types?

Tags: custom-post-types

I actually wanted to reply to [another](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/240138/ajax-live-search-for-post-title) post, unfortunately that is no longer possible.

Therefore a short and crisp question. ;-)

If I want to search in several post types, can I simply work with `'post_type' => 'post'` with comma values?

`'post_type' => 'post', 'Pages', 'etc ..'`

Comment: Not Ajax but interesting use of array with inputs to search in several post types: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/286586/limit-search-form-to-4-custom-post-types-only?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is documented here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-type-parameters

So to search for several post types you do:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'post', 'page', 'movie', 'book' )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```